# Error using Laravel resource controller update method within a grouped route

Tags: api, rest, laravel-4

I have a Laravel app which I'm using to create a RESTful API.

I'm having some issues with the **edit/update** methods in my **resource** controller when using a **grouped** route.

WHen I remove the route grouping the controller works as expected.

My routes look like:

```
Route::group(array('prefix' => 'api/v1'), function()
{ 
    Route::resource('/trip', 'TripController');
});
```

So using this my RESTFul endpoints should look like:

```
GET /api/v1/trip/{resource}

GET /api/v1/trip/{resource}/edit

PUT /api/v1/trip/update/{resource}

GET /api/v1/trip/create

POST /api/v1/trip/store/{resource}
```

etc.

All work except the **Edit** and **Update** endpoints.

When I hit **/api/v1/trip/{resource}/edit** I get the following error

```
Unable to generate a URL for the named route "trip.update" as such route does not exist.
```

My Controller Edit method is just a quick form for testing. It looks like:

```
public function edit($id)
{
  $oTrip = new Trip;
  $oTrip = $oTrip->find($id);

  echo Form::model($oTrip, array(
    'route' => array('trip.update', $oTrip->id),
    'method' => 'PUT'
    ));
  echo Form::text('headline');
  echo Form::text('description');
  echo Form::submit('Click Me!');
  echo Form::close();
}
```

Laravel seems to be unable to find **trip.update** when in the grouped route.
I think there is a problem with the Group prefix **api/v1**

When I comment out the group code just to read:

```
Route::resource('/trip', 'TripController');
```

...and access the uri just as **/trip/{resource}/edit** without the **api/v1** prefix everything works fine as expected.

Is there something I'm missing? 
I would really like to get this working with the grouping and **api/v1** prefix.

Comment: fixed. I ran `php artisan routes` in terminal and it listed available routes. It turns out the form::model route needed to read `api.v1..tripp.update`. I was unaware of the double period formatting... Hey ho. Fixed!

Comment: I think that's because you have to do `Route::resouce('trip')` instead of `Route::resource('/trip')`